# mock attribute assertion failure

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I am relatively new to python testing. I am using `unittest.mock` to test a Django view function. I am mocking a model. I am using TDD and once the view layer has got all its test passed, I will implement the changes in the model.

```
def new_list(request):
form = ItemForm(data=request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    list_ = List()
    list_.owner = request.user
    print(list_.owner)
    list_.save()
    form.save(for_list=list_)
    return redirect(list_)
else:

    return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form})
```

The test code is as follows:

```
@patch('lists.views.list')
@patch('lists.views.ItemForm')
def test_list_owner_is_saved_if_user_is_authenticated(
        self, mockItemFormClass, mockListClass):

    user = User.objects.create(email='a@b.com')
    self.client.force_login(user)

    self.client.post('/lists/new', data={'text': 'new item'})

    mock_list = mockListClass.return_value
    self.assertEqual(mock_list.owner, user)
```

The error that I get is as follows:

```
FAIL: test_list_owner_is_saved_if_user_is_authenticated (lists.tests.test_views.NewListTest)
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/mock.py", 
line 1204, in patched
 return func(*args, **keywargs)
File "/Users/asim/python-projects/django-todo-list/superlists/lists/tests/test_views.py", 
line 181, in test_list_owner_is_saved_if_user_is_authenticated
 self.assertEqual(mock_list.owner, user)
 AssertionError: <MagicMock name='list().owner' id='140457579271392'> != <User: User object 
 (a@b.com)>
```

I thought that Magic mock will return any assertion true. Any help and an explanation will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem, which was with patch decorator. The target path was wrong. Instead of `lists.views.list` it should have been `lists.views.List` because of this error the `List` model was not being mocked and hence the failure. Fixing that fixed my problem.

```
@patch('lists.views.List')
@patch('lists.views.ItemForm')
def test_list_owner_is_saved_if_user_is_authenticated(
        self, mockItemFormClass, mockListClass):
    user = User.objects.create(email='a@b.com')
    self.client.force_login(user)

    self.client.post('/lists/new', data={'text': 'new item'})

    mock_list = mockListClass.return_value
    mock_list.owner = user
    self.assertEqual(mock_list.owner, user)
```